# How to show all checked checkboxes also at reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a problem: my website is searching for checked checkboxes with a javascript.

```
$(function () {
    var $allELements           = $('.input-box');
    var $selectedElementsListing = $('#selectedElements');
    var $selectedElementsLabel   = $('#selectedElementsLabel');
    var $elementInfo         = $('.elementInfo ');

    $allELements.on('click', function () {
        $selectedElementsListing .html(
            $allELements.filter(':checked').map(function (index, checkbox) {
                return '<div>' + checkbox.title + '</div>';
            }).get().join('')
        );

        if ($selectedElementsListing .text().trim().length)
        {
            $selectedElementsListing .show();
            $selectedElementsLabel.show();
            $elementInfo.show();
        }
    });
});
```

So it is searching for checked checkboxes on my main page and is listing the name of the checkboxes on the lower left hand side (as information for the user).
My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="elementInfo" >
        <p>
            <strong id="selectedElementsLabel" ><u>Ausgewählte
                Magazine:</u></strong><br />
            <span id="selectedElements"></span>
        </p>
</div>
```

And it takes the checkbox names from this input field:

```
<input class="input-box" title="[[ElementName]]" type="checkbox" id="A[[ID]]" name="ID[]"
                                       value="[[ID]]" checked="[[checked_element]]" />
```

When I press reload, the information bar for the selected checkboxes isn't appearing. It is showing the checked checkboxes only if I press again any of them (then it shows all which were also selected)

Answer (score 1):

Every time the page is refreshed the DOM is re-rendered and no state is being stored anywhere. To preserve the state of checked boxes you can use localStorage to store the checked state and then upon page load you can read the localStorage and execute a function that checks them by checking local storage data.

```
// call this every time someone checks a box
window.localStorage.setItem('some key name of data', 'some data structure with checkbox state')

//Do this every time page is loaded
window.localStorage.getItem('previously used key name')
```

P.S. I assumed you don't have a backend api calling every time someone checks a box where you are preserving state

for further info do [visit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
A good read to [understand state management](https://codeburst.io/state-management-in-javascript-15d0d98837e1)